# $scope.param cannot be identified by function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a script in script.js as follows:

```
var app = angular.module("myModule", []);
app.controller('highchart', function($scope, chart) {

$scope.addchart = function() {
    console.log($scope.param);// print undefined !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    chart.addChartToUI($scope.param);
}

$scope.generate = function() {

    $scope.param=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        $scope.param[i] = Math.random();
    }
    console.log($scope.param);// print some number
}
});
```

Also I have another js file as follwos:

```
app.factory('chart', function() {
return {
    addChartToUI : function(paramsArr) {
        return Highcharts.chart('container', {

            xAxis : {
                categories : [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ]
            },

            series : [ {
                data : paramsArr
            } ]
        });
    }
};
```

});

Also my html code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
< Script src="javascript/angular.js">

</Script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<Script src="javascript/script.js"></Script>
  <script src="javascript/chartUtil.js"></script>

   </Script>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
   <body ng-app="myModule">

    <div ng-controller="highchart">
    <button id="b1" type="button" ng-click="generate()"      title="sssss">dddddddd</button>
</div>
</br>
</br>
</br>
 <div ng-controller="highchart">
    <button id="b2" type="button" ng-click="addchart()" />
    </br> </br>
    <div id="container">Placeholder for chart</div>

</div>
```

Now what I am trying to do is to first call generate by button b1 to create param then I will call addchart to draw the chart by buton b2  but when I do this the param inside generate gets created but it is undefined in addchart is there any way that I can share the param in between these 2 functions?

Comment: perfectly working here: http://jsbin.com/fanado/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @LouieAlmeda Please see my update it might help better, in my scenario does not work

Comment: ok, now I got what's the problem really is, I'll construct a fiddle for the solution

Comment: your code works perfectly fine for me.  Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rumba_alex47/Lt7aP/2237/

Comment: @HamedMinaee Any updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/goneka/1/edit?html,js,output)

Ok, so basically, you want your two controllers talk to each other. While your code may work the way you are doing it now, it will spawn a lot of problems in the future. So here's the better way I know to do things in angular.

First, every controller should only be used for a specific template, you should not use controllers for multiple template it should be strictly 1 controller for 1 template.

Now, for you to share an object to multiple controllers, you need to create a service to be shared by those controllers.

```
app.service('sharedService',function(){

  this.array = [];

});

app.controller('MainController', function(sharedService){

  sharedService.array = [1,2,3,4];

});

app.controller('AnotherController', function(sharedService){

  this.array = sharedService.array;

});
```

Please see my demo to see the whole code and how it works

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine in setting the scope.  Can you show me your code for calling the functions? I suspect that you maybe calling it in the wrong order or asynchronously so that means that addchart is called before generate can finish.

Try this:

```
app.controller('highchart', function($scope, chart) {

for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        $scope.param[i] = Math.random();
    }
    console.log($scope.param);// print some number

$scope.addchart = function() {
    console.log($scope.param);// print undefined !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    chart.addChartToUI($scope.param);
}
});
```

If this works then you can be sure that the scope is set correctly but the timing of the call is wrong.

Comment: For calling I just fist press button b1 to generate the data in scope then I press b2 to draw